# Individual boards on server for players in multi-player game

Tags: c#, asp.net

So far I have pretty much working game, but I really can't add all features as I want so far, because I can't solve that problem.

Let's say I have class Board, and each board have squares and pieces on those squares. 
I have many players connected to game, for each two players (and observers etc) I need to have single board. My question is where to start with that ?

I think first of all I need multiple instances of class Board, and then I need a way of binding those boards to and individual games (games are identified by GUIDs).

My question is where to start with this?

So far I have it working but it heavily uses database and it not really optimal and with my current approach I can't really do all things I wanted (move verification, dumping board state for future reference etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the complexity involved in storing the state of the game, board games can make excellent use of a non-relational database like MongoDB.

If this isn't an option (I assume you're using a full Microsoft stack) I'd still avoid a relational approach to the data storage. Without knowing the specifics of your game, I can only speculate. Because of that, I'll use scrabble as an example.

**Dumping The Board**

You could store the entire board state literally in a `boardState` table, like this (5x5 non regulation scrabble board :))

```
* * * o *
* w o r d
* * v * *
* * e * *
* * r * *
```

All processing could then be handled by the application logic. Imagine the database overhead if you were to try to relationally store this information!

**Move Verification**

Although scrabble doesn't have "moves" to speak of, this is something that should avoid the database anyway. All processes like word-checking, board limits, game logic, etc should be handled entirely in the application layer.

**Application Implementation**

If I were you, I'd continue on the path you were going with having many instances of the `Game` class, each containing a `Board` object. Store everything in memory and do all computations you need to in the application layer until something needs to persist (Board state if you want to save the game for later, game scores). At this time, dump it to the database.

---

Without knowing more about your game logic I can't speculate on how I'd handle it, so there's a 20,000 ft. top down view.

**Update:**

Based upon the new information, I'd just load a GameCollection class with GUID identifiers into memory. You'd be able to access the individual games through something like `colGames[GUID]` and boards with `colGames[GUID].Board`. Store all relevant information in the database after the game ends/is saved and remove it from memory.

Comment: That's chess game. Well I want to use SQL Server only for basic things, like storing game state in FEN string, store user ratings etc.

I don't have an problem with doing an singleplayer game, that's pretty much straightforward, true problem is here to make possible for multiple users play on single server.

I know that each game created must have it owns Board class, thing I don't know is the way to creating multiple independant of each other instances of board classes.

Comment: Haha. Seriously. "Because of the complexity involved"? You man because they ar zero complexity, I hope.

Comment: I meant the complexity of storing the information. Chess removes a lot of that complexity, but with a game like Scrabble (I use it as an example because of a project I read about of an infinitely large scrabble board) storing each letter placement in a look-up table proves to be quite a challenge. Dumping it into a single field makes more sense, rather than trying to figure out an abstract way to store each board piece in separate rows. I consider this fairly complex. I'll update the answer for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I did a multiplayer online card game as a facebook app about two years ago. Unfortunately the game is no longer up.
The game was hosted on Azure. The front end was done in Silverlight.
The way I persisted game state was as an entry in Azure Table Storage. I serialized game state using [ProtoBuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) (very, very fast). Each game had a GUID as a unique identifier. This GUID served as the Key in Azure Table Storage. Whenever a request came in, I would then deserialize the game state, process the message and if a change ocurred I would then overwrite the existing game state. I did use SQL Server for other purposes (stats, etc.) but not to persist game state. Maybe using SQL would have been faster than Azure Table Storage, but the performance was never an issue so I never looked into it.